# 2022 Should we abandon this election?

Tags: discussion, election

I am beginning to form the opinion that we as a community need to consider postponing this election.

The election before this, we had 6 candidates.

In this election we've got 2 candidates, one of which is running on the basis is that there would otherwise be no competition for the first one. Which I applaud, but not exactly a generally sound basis for candidacy (in my opinion of course).

I have no idea about the political mechanisms or rules in place to manage such a situation, but I suspect that if there was some way we could revisit this election at a later stage, that should happen.

I also don't really understand the metrics which we are using to decide to increase our moderator team, but I would say that an ill-suited moderator could cause more harm than good.

And I just want to say that I'm not really judging either of the two candidates, but the simple fact of the matter is the fewer candidates there are, the less chance of getting a good winning candidate. This is especially true if one of the candidates is running on the basis that they just want to provide the concept of a choice.

Comment: Honestly, it’s difficult for a volunteer moderator to do much harm. Mods are part of a team and there is very little they can do that can’t be reversed. It is rather unsatisfactory to just refrain from voting when you don’t like any of your choices, so you may want to weigh in on the Meta discussion [Can we have a "Reopen nominations" or "None of the above" option in moderator elections?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254458/273494).

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the link. I agree with what is said there.

Comment: Concerning the "more harm than good" part: I was (still am and will be whichever way this election goes) in favor of creating mechanisms to handle that better than we can today:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381399/revising-the-criteria-for-moderator-nominees/381425#381425

Answer (score 5):

With the initial meta post announcing an upcoming election we did have a fairly long window of time during which potential candidates could (plan to) self-nominate. While it's always nicer to have multiple candidates, even if only because it indicates a strong user community, it's not strictly required.

The second candidate's decision to nominate may have had the opposite effect of their stated intention, but just because we didn't get a week's extension on the nomination phase, that isn't really sufficient reason to pull the plug on an election. You'd also have to wonder if the number of candidates would really be substantially different if we were to postpone. We actually consciously decided to pursue an election at this time of the year since waiting any longer sees us enter the holiday season which has a sharp drop-off in community engagement.

> I also don't really understand the metrics which we are using to decide to increase our moderator team

The mod team decides internally when it makes sense for an election to take place. The CMs also regularly check in with the various sites and might sometimes ask if there's interest in an election. But usually it comes from within the team and the chief reason to expand the team is always to reduce the workload on the individual moderators. In my personal view it's also a good idea to regularly add new volunteers to the mod team so there's a strong base of people who can support the site and people feel less pressured to be "always on".

> I would say that an ill-suited moderator could cause more harm than good.

As ColleenV said the "harm" that can be done is limited. If finding a new moderator involved an interview and a moderator could do more "damage" I might agree with you. But that's not how elections work on SE. It's about community members in good standing stepping up to help out. And the community helps to pick the best person in case there are more volunteers than slots.

To my knowledge there are no "mechanisms" (certainly no *political* ones) for "managing such a situation". If the situation was much more extreme, such as if the only candidates all had candidate scores in the low single digits and/or were strangers to the site, we might request an intervention from the CMs. But I don't believe we're anywhere close to that kind of scenario.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I am kinda surprised, because 3 people upvoted when we were asked if someone would run for moderator, so I expected at least two other  candidates.

If there are candidates missing because of timing issues, I'm more than happy if the election gets moved a few weeks to give other people the chance to run, too. Nobody should be kept from running because they missed a specific week of SE.

I also support the "None of those" vote option as in the link given in the comments. Nobody should be forced to vote for anyone they don't want to vote for and nobody should be forced to vote for "the lesser evil" in their view. Anybody should vote for the candidate they want to see, and that must include "None of them!".

But I feel "I don't like the current candidates, lets postpone for a year and spin the wheel again" is not a good reasoning or plan to go forward.

Comment: 5 people upvoted. My issue, if I could call it that, is the number of people, rather than the people themselves. And also the motivations of one of them isn't the best.

Comment: Nobody is forced to vote. Most don't.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That is true, but the "None of them" option is still a valid point, because right now, "too lazy or doesn't care" and "enganged, but opposed to all candidates" are the same. In real life, where I live, people go vote and invalidate their ballot in protest. So that nobody can say "well, the candidates are all great, those people, they were just too lazy to get of the couch". I would love to see that option here, too at some point.

Answer (score 3):

We were told that an additional moderator would be desired. And that thought was approved by a 3 to 2 vote, so the election process was begun.

There are two candidates. The process has no requirement regarding the minimum number of candidates for a viable election.

IMHO, no reason to abandon the election.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason to abandon the election. I actually expected you to self nominate and would have voted for you based on your contributions to the site. But since you didn't we have what we have.

In terms of moderation my belief is that the commitment to the site is the most important factor. Whether I personally like the questions, comments and answers isn't. It's an international site, there's huge cultural gaps and attitudes between many of us.

> not exactly a generally sound basis for candidacy

If you believe you can be the change you want, you should nominate yourself. In the last election half of the candidates were just putting their names in the hat as well.

Comment: If you "expect someone to self nominate", you might want to actually nominate so they know someone is interested in their taking the role. Or find some other way to encourage.

Comment: @keshlam I expect everyone to do whatever they want, it's their internet. I didn't see a need to encourage anyone.

Comment: That's fine. I know in one organization I belong to as we elect president by whoever objects least...

Comment: @keshlam ahaha... I've seen that happen, whoever isn't hiding under their desk.... volunteered

Comment: I really need to start proofreading stuff written on the phone, and/or use gestural input more often rather than hunt and peck. I'm getting annoyed with my typo rate.

Answer (score 1):

I have no desire to run, and I think nvoig
t would do well.

I have a high opinion of you despite the fact that we have bumped heads.